# How to store universal references

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, perfect-forwarding, universal-reference

I need to store universal references inside a class (I am sure the referenced values will outlive the class). Is there a canonical way of doing so?

Here is a minimal example of what I have come up with. It seems to work, but I'm not sure if I got it right.

```
template <typename F, typename X>
struct binder
{
    template <typename G, typename Y>
    binder(G&& g, Y&& y) : f(std::forward<G>(g)), x(std::forward<Y>(y)) {}

    void operator()() { f(std::forward<X>(x)); }

    F&& f;
    X&& x;
};

template <typename F, typename X>
binder<F&&, X&&> bind(F&& f, X&& x)
{
    return binder<F&&, X&&>(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<X>(x));
}

void test()
{
    int i = 1;
    const int j = 2;
    auto f = [](int){};

    bind(f, i)();   // X&& is int&
    bind(f, j)();   // X&& is const int&
    bind(f, 3)();   // X&& is int&&
}
```

Is my reasoning correct or will this lead to subtle bugs? Also, is there a better (i.e., more concise) way to write the constructor? `binder(F&& f, X&& x)` will not work, since those are r-value references, thus disallowing `binder(f, i)`.

Comment: This is a shady - since it easily allows you to store a dangling reference... `bind(f, GetObj())`. Also calling `operator()` on `binder` repeatedly might be passing a function an already moved object as an rvalue reference. Basically, what you did is correct but I think it's bad design & error prone.

Comment: As I said, I can be sure the referenced variables outlive the binder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't "store a universal reference" because there's no such thing, there are only rvalue references and lvalue references.  "Universal reference" is Scott Meyers's convenient term to describe a syntax feature, *but it's not part of the type system*.

To look at specific details of the code:

```
template <typename F, typename X>
binder<F&&, X&&> bind(F&& f, X&& x)
```

Here you're instantiating `binder` with reference types as the template arguments, so in the class definition there is no need to declare the members as rvalue-references, because they already *are* reference types (either lvalue or rvalue as deduced by `bind`).  This means you've always got more `&&` tokens than needed, which are redundant and disappear due to reference collapsing.

If you're sure `binder` will always be instantiated by your `bind` function (and so always be instantiated with reference types) then you could define it like this:

```
template <typename F, typename X>
struct binder
{
    binder(F g, X y) : f(std::forward<F>(g)), x(std::forward<X>(y)) {}

    void operator()() { f(std::forward<X>(x)); }

    F f;
    X x;
};
```

In this version the types `F` and `X` are reference types, so it's redundant to use `F&&` and `X&&` because they're either already lvalue references (so the `&&` does nothing) or they're rvalue references (so the `&&` does nothing in this case too!)

Alternatively, you could keep `binder` as you have it and change `bind` to:

```
template <typename F, typename X>
binder<F, X> bind(F&& f, X&& x)
{
    return binder<F, X>(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<X>(x));
}
```

Now you instantiate `binder` with either an lvalue reference type or an object (i.e. non-reference) type, then inside `binder` you declare members with the additional `&&` so they are either lvalue reference types or rvalue reference types.

Furthermore, if you think about it, you don't need to store rvalue reference members.  It's perfectly fine to store the objects by lvalue references, all that matters is that you *forward* them correctly as lvalues or rvalues in the `operator()` function. So the class members could be just `F&` and `X&` (or in the case where you always instantiate the type with reference arguments anyway, `F` and `X`)

So I would simplify the code to this:

```
template <typename F, typename X>
struct binder
{
    binder(F& g, X& y) : f(g), x(y) { }

    void operator()() { f(std::forward<X>(x)); }

    F& f;
    X& x;
};

template <typename F, typename X>
binder<F, X> bind(F&& f, X&& x)
{
    return binder<F, X>(f, x);
}
```

This version preserves the desired type in the template parameters `F` and `X` and uses the right type in the `std::forward<X>(x)` expression, which is the only place where it's needed.

Finally, I find it more accurate and more helpful to think in terms of the deduced type, not just the (collapsed) reference type:

```
bind(f, i)();   // X is int&, X&& is int&
bind(f, j)();   // X is const int&, X&& is const int&
bind(f, 3)();   // X is int, X&& is int&&
```

Answer (score 1):

`binder(F&& f, X&& x)` [works fine](http://liveworkspace.org/code/Zcoyr%240).

`F` and `X` are reference types (they are the types given in the template instantiation `binder<F&&, X&&>`), and so `f` and `x` become universal reverences following the usual reference collapsing rules.

Other than that, the code looks fine (as long as you really can ensure that the referenced variables outlive the binder).