# How I can a take a pointer to a universal reference?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have this code:

```
char X[64];

template <typename E>
void f (E &&e, size_t len)
{
    memset(X, 0, 64);
    memcpy(X, &e, len);
}
```

that call with this:

```
const char* tx = "hello!";
f(tx, strlen(tx));
```

but when I print variable X is not what I want!
I think that my universal reference to **e** (that is declared as **E&& e**) is not take correctly.

Any idea?

Comment: [There is no such thing as a universal reference.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14762132/981959)

It's not part of the type system, it's just a (non-standard) term that is (arguably) useful to understand argument deduction and reference collapsing.

A reference must be an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your universal reference[*] turns into an lvalue reference to `const char*` after type deduction (`E` is deduced to be `const char*&`).

Thus, instead of this:

```
memcpy(X, &e, len);
//        ^^
//        This is a pointer to a pointer to const char!
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You should use this:

```
memcpy(X, e, len);
```

---

[*] The term "universal reference" was introduced by Scott Meyers and it is *not* part of the C++11 Standard. The Standard only defines reference collapsing rules, and the abstraction of a universal reference is only meant to provide an easier understanding of how those rules work.

Answer (score 6):

`E` will be deduced to be `const char*&` in this case and so `e` will be of type `const char*&` too (after reference collapsing). So `e` is a pointer object. Then you do `&e`, which is taking the address of the pointer. What you want is to just pass the pointer denoted by `e` directly to `memcpy`, since it points to the data you want to copy:

```
memcpy(X, e, len);
```

The type deduction of `e`:

```
E&& → const char*& && → const char*&
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. If you want to copy regular variables to your buffer, but data for pointers, you can provide specialization:

char X[64];

```
template <typename E>
void f (E &&e, size_t len)
{
    memset(X, 0, 64);
    memcpy(X, &e, len);
}

template <typename E>
void f (E *e, size_t len)
{
    memset(X, 0, 64);
    memcpy(X, e, len);
}
```

This should work, but len parameter for "universal" reference seems to be redundant in this case.